# NameError: name 'ptclType' is not defined

Tags: python

I am beginer in python.
When I try to run code below, it gives NameError.
The purpose of the code is printing out word in readline.
I searched some forums about this, but I couldn't find proper solution.
It seems that the variable doesn't appeared at outside of if statement.

```
import sys
f = open("./multPhiCorr_741_25nsDY_cfi.py",'r')
lines = f.readlines()
if line.find('name') != -1:
    Section = line[23:-4]       # slice charactor index
    print ('[%s]') % Section
if line.find('type') != -1:
    ptclType = line[21:-3]      # slice charactor index
if line.find('varType') != -1:
    nameParVar = line[24:-3]    # slice charactor index
if line.find('fx') != -1:
    formula = line[21:-3]       # slice charactor index
if line.find('etaMin') != -1:
    netaMin = line[24:-3]       # slice charactor index
print ('{%s 1 eta 1 %s %s}') % (ptclType,nameParVar,formula)

[/u/user/sangilpark/pytest]$ python convert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 19, in <module>
   print ('{%s 1 eta 1 %s %s}') % (ptclType,nameParVar,formula)
NameError: name 'ptclType' is not defined
```

Comment: What would ptclType equal if the line does not contain "type"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptclType` is only defined if your conditional "if" statement is met. Thus, when you try to print it, it's not defined. Try to assign default values first:

```
import sys
f = open("./multPhiCorr_741_25nsDY_cfi.py",'r')
lines = f.readlines()
ptclType = None
nameParVar = None
formula = None
if line.find('name') != -1:
    Section = line[23:-4]       # slice charactor index
    print ('[%s]') % Section
if line.find('type') != -1:
    ptclType = line[21:-3]      # slice charactor index
if line.find('varType') != -1:
    nameParVar = line[24:-3]    # slice charactor index
if line.find('fx') != -1:
    formula = line[21:-3]       # slice charactor index
if line.find('etaMin') != -1:
    netaMin = line[24:-3]       # slice charactor index
print ('{%s 1 eta 1 %s %s}') % (ptclType,nameParVar,formula)
```

As you can see, I simply defined everything in your print statement with a default value (at the top) in case the "if" statement isn't met.